# Firebase Retrieve Realtime Data With Cardview

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Basically I am making an App in which I am using `firebase` and trying to retrieve `real-time database` like I am storing an image in `firebase storage` and copying the "download URL" link and pasting it in firebase database so that whenever I run my app, there should be an image under which title and description should come. I basically want to add images, titles and description to the firebase database and retrieve in the app.

Activity_main:--

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/activity_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        >
        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/recyclerview">
        </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

individual_row:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
            android:id="@+id/image"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:text="title"
            android:id="@+id/title"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="description"
            android:id="@+id/description"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Firebase Database rules:--

> {
>     "rules": {
>      ".read": "true",
>      ".write": "true"
>     }
>    }

Firebase Storage Rules:--

```
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match[enter image description here][1] /{allPaths=**} {
      // Allow access by all users
      allow read, write;
    }
  }
}
```

MainActivity:--

```
package com.namy86.dtunews;

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private DatabaseReference myref;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        recyclerView=(RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        myref= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("/blog");
        FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Blog,BlogViewHolder> recyclerAdapter=new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Blog,BlogViewHolder>(
                Blog.class,
                R.layout.individual_row,
                BlogViewHolder.class,
                myref
        ) {
            @Override
            protected void populateViewHolder(BlogViewHolder viewHolder, Blog model, int position) {
                viewHolder.setTitle(model.getTitle());
                viewHolder.setDescription(model.getDescription());
                viewHolder.setImage(model.getImage());
            }
        };
        recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerAdapter);
    }
    public static class BlogViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        View mView;
        TextView textView_title;
        TextView textView_decription;
        ImageView imageView;
        public BlogViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            mView=itemView;
            textView_title = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.title);
            textView_decription = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.description);
            imageView=(ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.image);
        }
        public void setTitle(String title)
        {
            textView_title.setText(title+"");
        }
        public void setDescription(String description)
        {
            textView_decription.setText(description);
        }
        public void setImage(String image)
        {
            Picasso.with(mView.getContext())
                    .load(image)
                    .into(imageView);
        }
    }
}
```

Blog(Activity):--

```
package com.namy86.dtunews;

public class Blog {
    private String title,description,image;
    public Blog() {
    }
    public Blog(String title, String description, String image) {
        this.title = title;
        this.description = description;
        this.image = image;
    }
    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }
    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }
    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }
    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }
    public String getImage() {
        return image;
    }
    public void setImage(String image) {
        this.image = image;
    }
}
```

Firebase Database Structure:-

demofirebase-1faa

- Post1

  ```
  -Description1="First Post"
  -Image1="https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/demofirebase-1faaa.appspot.com/o/Unknown.jpg?alt=media&token=6f5ade3c-d615-4871-90a0-1b4a55e6e00c"
  -Title1="Namy"
  ```
- Post2

  ```
  -Description2="Second Post"
  -Image2="https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/demofirebase-1faaa.appspot.com/o/Unknown.jpg?alt=media&token=6f5ade3c-d615-4871-90a0-1b4a55e6e00c"
  -Title2="Naman"
  ```

Comment: Please add you database structure.

Comment: @AlexMamo I Have Added The Database Structure

Comment: Please add it correctly.

Comment: What do you want to know exactly? How to send the data or how to retrieve it and correctly put into the card?

Comment: @HugoCastelani  Yes I want to know how to store the data and then retrieve or put correctly in the app

Comment: @AlexMamo Added again Sir

Comment: @HugoCastelani Its done . The problem is resolved , Actually I Have Used "Image" in my firebase database while actually in main Activity I am using "image". So that was the reason of not doing anything.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you already have your project properly configured, you can send your data to firebase by getting a reference, creating a new node (as Alex Mamo said, you just can't send it without a specific node) and fitting your object inside it. See below:

```
// get your reference
DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

// refer your child and use push to generate a new unique node, then put your object
reference.child("blog").push().setValue(blog);
```

Joining firebase and adapter can be done in two ways: show objects as they are retrieved or show them all at once.

### Object by object:

Create an interface to receive items:

```
public interface ItemListener<T> {
    void onItemAdded(@NonNull final T item);
    void onItemRemoved(@NonNull final T item);
}
```

In your DAO, create a method to get all objects from your blog node:

```
public void getBlogList(@NonNull final ItemListener listener) {
    FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("blog").orderByKey()
        .addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                final Blog blog = dataSnapshot.getValue(Blog.class);
                listener.onItemAdded(blog);
            }

            @Override 
            public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                final Blog blog = dataSnapshot.getValue(Blog.class);
                listener.onItemRemoved(blog);
            }

            @Override public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {}
            @Override public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {}
            @Override public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
        });
}
```

Inside your adapter, call the method above in constructor, send received blog to a list and notify:

```
public class Adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<BlogViewHolder> {
    private List<Blog> mBlogList;

    public Adapter() {  
        getBlogList(new ItemListener<Blog>() {
            @Override
            public void onItemAdded(@NonNull final Blog blog) {
                mBlogList.add(blog);
                notifyItemInserted(mBlogList.size);
            }

            @Override
            public void onItemRemoved(@NonNull final Blog blog) {
                for (Integer i = 0; i < mBlogList.size(); i++) {
                    final Blog innerBlog = mBlogList.get(i);

                    // since you don't store a key, you gotta check all attributes
                    if (innerBlog.getTitle.equals(blog.getTitle) &&
                        innerBlog.getDescription.equals(blog.getDescription) &&
                        innerBlog.getImage.equals(blog.getImage)) {

                        mBlogList.remove(innerBlog);
                        notifyItemRemoved(i);
                   }
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public BlogViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        return new BlogViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.individual_row, parent, false));
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(BlogViewHolder holder, int position) {
        final Blog blog = holder.get(position);
        holder.setTitle(blog.getTitle());
        holder.setDescription(blog.getDescription());
        holder.setImage(blog.getImage());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mBlogList.size();
    }
}
```

### All objects at once:

Create an interface to receive a list:

```
public interface ListListener<T> {
    void onListRetrieved(@NonNull final List<T> list);
}
```

In your DAO, create a method to get all objects at once from your blog node:

```
public void getBlogList(@NonNull final ListListener listener) {
    final List<Blog> blogList = new ArrayList<>();

    FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("blog")
        .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for (final DataSnapshot innerDataSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    final Blog blog = innerDataSnapshot.getValue(Blog.class);
                    blogList.add(blog);
                }

                listener.onListRetrieved(blogList);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
        });
}
```

Inside your adapter, call the method above in constructor, clone received list and notify:

```
public class Adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<BlogViewHolder> {
    private List<Blog> mBlogList;

    public Adapter() {  
        getBlogList(new ListListener<Blog>() {
            @Override
            public void onListRetrieved(@NonNull final List<Blog> blogList) {
                mBlogList.addAll(blogList);
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
    }

    // same code as first Adapter
}
```

Then, you can add this adapter to your `RecyclerView`:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ...
    recyclerView.setAdapter(new Adapter());
}
```

Comment: I recommend creating a separate file for each code part.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have `Image1`, `Image2` and so on as keys in your Firebase database. Your keys must me always the same in each node. Your database should look like this:

```
demofirebase-1faa
    |
    --- Post1
    |    |
    |    --- Description: "First Post"
    |    |
    |    --- Image: "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/demofirebase-1faaa.appspot.com/o/Unknown.jpg?alt=media&token=6f5ade3c-d615-4871-90a0-1b4a55e6e00c"
    |    |
    |    --- Title: "Namy"
    |
    --- Post2
         |
         --- Description: "Second Post"
         |
         --- Image: "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/demofirebase-1faaa.appspot.com/o/Unknown.jpg?alt=media&token=6f5ade3c-d615-4871-90a0-1b4a55e6e00c"
         |
         --- Title: "Naman"
```

To get the image according to this database schema, please use the following code:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            String image = ds.child("image").getValue(String.class);
            Log.d("TAG", image);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
};
rootRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);
```

Comment: Where should I add this code and should I delete my little bit original code also?  @AlexMamo

Comment: This is not a copy paste code. This is the way you need to query your database to obtain the result you need. But first of all you need to have the database structure as in the above schema.

Comment: Its done . The problem is resolved , Actually I Have Used "Image" in my firebase database while actually in main Activity I am using "image". So that was the reason of not doing anything.

Comment: Do you think that my answer helped you?